# Identify this font

Tags: font-identification, web-fonts

Could anyone tell me what font is used on the navigation menu of this site:

http://www.clementineandbloom.com/

Comment: The theme is by [Store Front Themes called "Edge"](http://storefrontthemes.com/themes/edge/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font is called [Champagne & Limousines](http://www.dafont.com/champagne-limousines.font?text=LAMPSHADES):

[image: Champagne & Limousines screenshot]

I found this out by mining the source code. With web fonts, you can usually figure it out by inspecting elements or looking at the source.

[image: Source Code]

Comment: Good grief. Cufon?!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Heh, yeah...